# REST API request android not working

Tags: android

I followed a REST API CRUD tutorial form [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/), but i ran into a bit of a problem, it doesn't post the data to my MySQL database. Before this, i've tested my PHP API with Postman, and it works normally. Here is my RequestHandler class code :

```
package com.telkomuniversity.iflab.spriflab;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class RequestHandler {

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if(first){
            first = false;
        }
        else{
            result.append("&");
        }

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams){
    URL url;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     try{
         url = new URL(requestURL);

         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
         conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);

         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
         writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

         writer.flush();
         writer.close();
         os.close();
         int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

         if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;
            while((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(response);
            }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return sb.toString();
}

public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(s + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

And here's the PerformNetworkRequest inner class :

```
private class PerformNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    String url;
    HashMap<String, String> params;
    int requestCode;

    public PerformNetworkRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        try{
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            if(!object.getBoolean("error")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);


        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My question is, which part did i do wrong because i'm not getting what i am doing wrong and is there a good solution? Because the app doesn't crash and doesn't showed any exception in the log. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Have you considered using Retrofit library? It should abstract you from the  problems you describe here.

Comment: Try with HTTP library like `Volly` or `Retrofit`

Comment: I don't see you using your AsyncTask anywhere

Comment: @NelsonAlmendra i haven't actually because i'm a newbie so i followed the simplest example i could find

Comment: @IncredibleHat done

Comment: @llehcram Sure but making the requests by hand will probably generate more bugs and problems than using a library that encapsulates that code for you. It will certainly simplify your code base.

Comment: @NelsonAlmendra okay i'm gonna search for retrofit basics instead